# gstreamer-sharp C# application deployment

Tags: winforms, deployment, gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

Can anyone tell me the proper way to deploy a C# WinForms application that uses gstreamer-sharp?  The only way I can get it to work is to work is by setting the gstreamer bin directory as my Application's working directory.

I have seen examples trying to temporarily set the application's path to the various gstreamer directories, but this still does not work for me and I get errors that DLL's are missing.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86\\bin\\");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86\\lib\\");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86\\");
```

Should I just deploy all of the gstreamer DLLs inside my application's bin driectory?  I was hoping to have them run the installer and then my application could could reference it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <pre> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732470/gstreamer-sharp-failed-to-create-pipeline/59043773#59043773
<pre>

Answer (score 1):

Adding the bin directory only should be enough. You can look at https://github.com/Vocaluxe/Vocaluxe/blob/develop/Vocaluxe/Lib/Sound/Playback/GstreamerSharp/CGstreamerSharpAudio.cs to see how initialization is done in Vocaluxe.

Comment: I thought that adding just the gstreamer bin to the path worked, but here I still had it set as the working dir in Visual Studio.  If I take it out and just manually add to the PATH or temporarily in code (as you suggested) I get the following "Entry Point Not Found" Windows pop-up, **_"The procedure entry point g_socket_send_messages could not be located in the dynamic link library libgio-2.0-0.dll."_** when the **Parse.Launch(strPipelineDesc)** method is executed.

Comment: Can you run gst-launch from the bin directory successfully?

Comment: Yes I can do gst-launch successfully from the bin dir

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution I can come up with is manually putting the gstreamer bin directory in the system's PATH.