# GStreamer-sharp failed to create pipeline

Tags: c#, wpf, gstreamer-1.0, gstreamer-sharp

I try to display RTSP stream using Gstreamer in my WPF application.

So I did so far:

- installed GStreamer into loal folder F:/gstreamer
- Created new WPF application
- Added glib-sharp and gstreamer-sharp as dependencies.

The code below I use to init the library:

```
Gst.Application.Init(); // (1)

mainLoop = new GLib.MainLoop();
mainGLibThread = new System.Threading.Thread(mainLoop.Run);
mainGLibThread.Start();

Element uriDecodeBin = ElementFactory.Make("playbin", "uriDecodeBin0"); // (2)
```

> Unable to load DLL 'libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll': The specified module could not be found.

on line (1). If I copy all the gstreamer dlls into bin/Debug folder the exception gone but `ElementFactory.Make` in line (2) always returns `null` without any exception. If I try to do something like

```
Parse.Launch(@"videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink")
```

to test the library functionality I get error:

> no element "videotestsrc"

but if I run it from command line:

> gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

that works as expected.

So my question - how to get GStreamer-sharp work?

Answer (score 0):

Change path to GStream and add this code before start

```
        string path = @"G:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\"; // path to your gstream
        string pluginpath = @"G:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\"; // path to your gstream
        string registry = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "registry.bin");

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + path);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GST_PLUGIN_PATH", pluginpath + ";" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GST_PLUGIN_PATH"));
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH_1_0", pluginpath + ";" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH_1_0"));
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH", pluginpath + ";" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH"));
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GST_DEBUG", "*:4");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GST_DEBUG_FILE", System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "gstreamer.log"));
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GST_REGISTRY", registry);
```